# Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Void' to expected argument type '(Any) -> Void'

Tags: ios, swift

I have two functions. The first one is taking an Integer as parameter and returns nothing:

```
func myIntFunction(_ arg: Int) -> Void {
    print(arg)
}
```

The second one is taking a function of type `(Any) -> Void` as parameter and returns nothing:

```
func myAnyFunction(arg: @escaping (Any) -> Void) {
    arg(5)
}
```

So there is something I am not catching here obviously as Int is a subset of Any right?

So if I trying to use this code:

```
myAnyFunction(arg: myIntFunction)
```

I get a compilation error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Void' to expected argument type '(Any) -> Void'
```

and a suggestion to change my code into:

```
myAnyFunction(arg: myIntFunction as! (Any) -> Void)
```

But then I get a runtime error as `(Int) -> Void` cannot be casted into `(Any) -> Void`

What am I not getting there? I thought with a method/function asking for an argument of type `Any`, giving an `Integer` as argument would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So there is something I am not catching here obviously as `Int` is a subset of `Any` right?

Right. However, since `Int` is a subset of `Any`, a closure that expects `Any` can be passed an `Int`, but not the other way around (this cast is not possible either).

Imagine that it were possible to cast a closure taking an `Int` to a closure taking `Any`. Now the users would be able to pass an object other than `Int` to your closure, rendering type checking irrelevant. That is why casting among closure types like that is not allowed.

You can create another closure that calls `myIntFunction`, like this:

```
myAnyFunction(arg: {a -> Void in myIntFunction(a as! Int)})
```